# compress [compression] tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

There is no need for the verb forms to exist.

- [compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compression) ← [data-compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-compression)
- [decompression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decompression) ← [decompress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decompress)
- [decompression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decompression) ← [uncompress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uncompress)

Then there is a question whether [compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compression) ← [decompression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decompression) synonymization should be done. I think it does, because compression always entails decompression in the same way as encryption and decryption (already synonyms) are two sides of the same coin.

**Final proposal:**

- [compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compression) ← [decompression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decompression)
- [compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compression) ← [data-compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-compression)
- [compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compression) ← [decompress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decompress)
- [compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compression) ← [uncompress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uncompress)

[image]

Comment: Yes, even the one you are not quite confident enough about is a good synonym to make.

Comment: If you are uncertain about [tag:compression] ← [tag:decompression], then your first recommendation should be [tag:decompression] ← [tag:uncompress]. That said, I agree with Deduplicator that it is a good idea.

Comment: This question is *screaming* for `Compress [compress]` as its title. Plzz?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Sorry, no can't do. That would be [lossy-compression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lossy-compression)

Comment: @Pekka웃 (compress) [\1ion]

Comment: I'm surprised this hasn't gone through yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with this was that, [decompress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decompress) was already a synonym of [decompression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decompression). As we can't have synonym chains, we have to first break the synonym between [decompress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decompress) and [decompression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decompression). I have done this now, and created the synonyms as shown in the question.

Final:

- [compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compression) × 6738 ← [decompression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decompression) × 860
- [compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compression) ← [data-compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-compression) (already present)
- [compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compression) × 6738 ← [decompress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/decompress) × 0
- [compression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compression) × 6738 ←    [uncompress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uncompress) × 97